# Pause between hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide();
 $(".swap-image-1b").show().sleep(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1b").hide();
 $(".swap-image-1a").show().sleep(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide();
 $(".swap-image-1c").show();
```

Can someone show me how to properly make these images pause between hiding and showing them? Thanks so much.

Comment: You have it backwards; move the .sleep calls after the hide calls instead. The functions are executed in the order you write them, so as it stands it sleeps after showing each image, instead of after hiding.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a callback function:

```
$(".swap-image-1b").show(3000, function() {
  $(".swap-image-1b").hide();
});
```

The `.hide()` and `.show()` methods accepts the next params:

---

> **`.show( [duration ] [, complete ] )`**
>
> **duration (default: 400)**
>
> Type: Number or String A string or number determining how long the
>   animation will run.
>
> **complete**
>
> Type: Function() A function to call once the animation is complete,
>   called once per matched element.

---

> **`.show( options )`**
>
> **options**
>
> Type: PlainObject A map of additional options to pass to the method.

You can find more details in the documentation:

- [**`.hide()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [**`.show()`**](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the duration for the $.show() and $.hide() functions.

```
$('#example').show(1000) // 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sleep()` method after hiding and before showing, not after showing.

```
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide().sleep(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1b").show();
 $(".swap-image-1b").hide().sleep(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1a").show();
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide().sleep(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1c").show();
```

You can also specify the duration for the `hide()` method as the first argument.

```
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide(3000);//3 seconds
 $(".swap-image-1b").show();
 $(".swap-image-1b").hide(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1a").show();
 $(".swap-image-1a").hide(3000);
 $(".swap-image-1c").show();
```

See the documentation:

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses, now having tried this I think I was trying to use hide and show to create a simple animation of three pics but this is fading them in and out which is not what I need....1a is on the screen I just need that pic to disappear right away and replace it right away with 1b for a couple of seconds and then have that disappear right away and have 1c left on the screen... no fade outs. any other way to do that?

Comment: I think what I need is just a 2-3 second pause after 1b displays and then it instantly disappears and 1c instantly displays